# How to Iterate through Json schema and values based on keys

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON schema. I want to read it line by line and populate all "name" key values to an ArrayList of String until it reaches a key called entity. When it reaches to an entity I want to read the entity value and populate it to a String.After that loop should go through the remains of the schema and read all the "name" and populate to a new ArrayList until it meets another entity and so on...

I've only included a part of the schema it's a valid schema.

```
{
  "entity": "Data",
  "xement": [
    {
      "code": "MA",
      "entity": "MH",
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "Id",
          "position": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "mdc",
          "position": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "minr",
          "position": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "mx",
          "position": 11
        }
      ],
      "maltr": [
        {
          "name": "sub",
          "position": 13
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "war",
      "entity": "subl",
      "attr": [
        {
          "name": "se",
          "position": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "go",
          "position": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "re",
          "position": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "pr",
          "position": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "mxp",
          "position": 11
        },
        {
          "name": "rpl",
          "position": 45
        },
        {
          "name": "rtr",
          "position": 47
        },
        {
          "name": "net",
          "position": 55
        }
      ],
      "groups": [
        {
          "entity": "ro",
          "grattr": [
            {
              "name": "rmn",
              "position": 5
            },
            {
              "name": "aib",
              "position": 6
            },
            {
              "name": "nxr",
              "position": 7
            },
            {
              "name": "xer",
              "position": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "rog",
              "position": 9
            },
            {
              "name": "ccc",
              "position": 16
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: deserialize into pojo using objectmapper.

Comment: @Nitika
The thing is I can't create pojos from this cause I am trying to auto generate pojos based on this schema in the first place.

Comment: Obtaining a `Map<String, Object>` could help?

Comment: How does it help @Renato

Comment: If you obtain a Map you can iterate over his keys and if the corrisponding value is a map, you can do it again ricorsively

Comment: your json is not valid. please post valid json.

Comment: @Nitika I've mentioned that.anyway I edited it now its valid

Comment: I think you mean "I have some JSON" because this is not a "JSON Schema". It sounds like your question is "How do I load and process JSON data?" right? You have to convert the JSON to something you can use first, so it sounds like you probably need to do to POJOs (maybe using Jackson?), process, then create new POJOs after the processing.

Comment: Will [jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) be useful? It works like XPath.

Comment: @Relequestual Thank you for pointing it out.I am quite new to json schemas.So it's a json Isn't there a way to go through all the names as I am unable to use POJOs cause The whole point of the project is to generate POJOs based on this schema.

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks will check it out

Comment: "JSON Schema" is a specific thing. You have JSON data here, not a JSON Schema. I don't know Java, sorry, but if you want to do processing based on the JSON, you have to load it in somehow. There's no reason it can't be a two step process to make your end result POJOs.

Comment: OK, POJO is clearly not what I thought it was. You still need to load and process the JSON somehow.